# Changing domain for site running on raspberry pi server

Tags: domain

I am fairly new to web development, and have started to learn some concepts by playing around with a raspberry pi.

I have just turned my pi into a web server and created a wordpress site using the following guide: [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/web-server-wordpress/worksheet.md).

At the moment I know how to access the site only by typing in the pi's ip address. How would I go setting up a conventional wordpress domain (like joesprojectspace.wordpress.com)? I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

The missing link is to configure a DNS that will resolve the domain name to the IP address, and configure a virtual host for the domain on the Apache. Both of these topics are off-topic here and have a lot of documentation on the web therefor I am not going to get into specific details.